# do not require UAC elevation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac, wix3.11

I have a wix setup that can be installed per user and per machine.

I use the `WixUI_Advanced` dialog to choose between perUser and perMachine.

However, even as a user the setup eventually requests UAC privilges and I can't tell why.

I verified that with setting `InstallPrivileges="limited"` the setup runs fine.

```
<Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" 
    Description="!(loc.ProductDescription)"
    Comments="!(loc.Comments) $(var.VersionNumber)" InstallPrivileges="limited" />
```

Is there a way to conditionally set `InstallPrivileges` based on the user selection?

Answer (score -1):

The InstallPrivileges attribute maps to bit 3 of the [Word Count Summary Info property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/word-count-summary). This enables and disable the elevation itself, and is intended for using in packages that know ahead of time that they will install only per-user.

Windows Installer 5 introduced [Single Package Authoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/single-package-authoring) which allows you to use MSIINSTALLPERUSER and ALLUSERS together to do two things conditionally:

- suppress the elevation prompt
- redirect machine locations for files and registry keys to per-user locations

So if you want a conditional elevation and a conditional per-user installation, and if you can safely require Windows 7 or later, figure out the best way to conditionally set MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1 and ALLUSERS=2. (I don't know if there are any prebuilt dialog sets that do this for WiX or not.)

Or do it manually: use a launcher that selects between two different packages; they should differ primarily on the InstallPrivileges attribute, and the locations where they install data.